Show only 1 line from the prior screenful?
How may I tweak the Vim <C-F> command to show only 1 line from the prior screenful?
Well I tried to map a normal mode command that scrolls forward by 1 line less than the number of lines in the window, and multiply that by the prefix arg if given.
With no prefix arg this works properly:
:no <expr> <C-F> (v:count1*(winheight(0)-1))."\<C-E>"

But with a prefix arg it appears to both evaluate the expression and then also prefix the prefix arg to the result, so if the window shows 11 lines it scrolls from line 1 to:
prefix scrolls to
 ----   --------
 none       11
   1       111
   2       221
   9       991
  10     10101

With or without a prefix arg this at least shows the proper number of lines to scroll, so that seems like progress:
:no <C-F> :<C-u>echo (v:count1*(winheight(0)-1))<cr>

But, with or without a prefix arg, this doesn't work, it moves the cursor in inconsistent ways and doesn't scroll:
:no <C-F> :<C-u>normal (v:count1*(winheight(0)-1))."\<c-e>"<cr>

I'm stumped.  How would you do it?

:help 'lines' is the total number of lines in the whole "screen" taken by Vim, including the command-line, the tab-line (if any), the status-line (if any), the tool-bar (if any), and, eventually, other windows than the current one. This makes it a very poor fit for what you are trying to do. Even if you NEVER EVER use those features, you will at least need to factor in :help 'cmdheight'. :help winheight() would be a better starting point.

Thank you i rewrote the question accordingly.

I would do:
:nnoremap <c-f> <c-f><c-y>

It works fine with count or without count.
Or to continue where you started:
:nnoremap <C-f> <cmd>execute 'normal' (v:count1*(winheight(0)-1)) . "\<c-e>"<cr>

Remark: the first versiin:
:no <expr> <C-F> (v:count1*(winheight(0)-1))."\<C-E>"

Doesn't work because the original count is still there. If winheight is 11

with 1 you have 1. 1 * 10 or `110
with 2 you have 2 . 2 * 10 or 220

Remark: in your second version I suspect Vim to not interpret the argument of the normal command as an expression but as pure literal list of characters entered by the user.

Your first one shows 3 prior lines.  This shows just one:
:no <c-f> <c-f><c-e>

But a prefix arg doesn't repeat the entire mapping.  Your second one looks like a winner, Thanks!

Your second one works from the : prompt, but when defined in the VIMINIT environment variable, invoking complains E117: Unknown function: normal.  What's up with that?

Thanks for the  feedback :-) It is odd. It should be the same behavior. Did you type it the same way? In particular do you have a space between 'normal' and (v:count1*(winheight(0)-1)) . "\<c-e>"<cr>?

it was a quoting issue, fixed it, it works, thanks again.

Thanks for the feedback! I'm glad you solved your problem :-)
